# Passport-azure-ad MSAL Using BearerStrategy gives error

Tags: azure-ad-msal, bearer-token, msal.js, msal-react, passport-azure-ad

Client(React Js) - @azure/msal-react, @azure/msal-browser
Server(Express Js) - Passport-azure-ad

```
var options = {
    identityMetadata:"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tennant-id>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    clientID:"<client-id>",
    validateIssuer:true,
    issuer: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tennant-id>/v2.0",
    passReqToCallback: false,
    allowMultiAudiencesInToken: false,
    audience:"<client-id>",
    loggingLevel: "info",
    loggingNoPII: false,
    scope: ["User.Read"],
  };

  var bearerStrategy = new BearerStrategy(options,
    function(token, done) {
      log.info('verifying the user');
      log.info(token, 'was the token retreived');
      findById(token.oid, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          // "Auto-registration"
          log.info('User was added automatically as they were new. Their oid is: ', token.oid);
          users.push(token);
          owner = token.oid;
          return done(null, token);
        }
        owner = token.oid;
        return done(null, user, token);
      });
    }
  );
```

Error log - {"name":"AzureAD: Bearer Strategy","hostname":"xxxxx-xxxxx","pid":xxxxx,"level":x,"msg":"authentication failed due to: invalid signature","time":"xxxx","v":0}

Though the server receives the accessToken from the client in Headers as Authorization Bearer Token to which it parses and also decodes the token to provide the userInfo. But after generating the pemKey I get the above error log.

What could be the reason for this error log.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you decode the access token (using https://jwt.ms) and check the value you have on the "aud" claim? My guess is that you are acquiring an access token for Microsoft Graph API, which you are not be able to validate - only MS Graph can validate tokens issued for MS Graph itself.

Comment: yes the issue was when it validates the token using jwt, that got resolved by simply changing the scope of the accessToken passed from the client to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

Generated the **access token** via Postman using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:user.read
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the access token, I got the **same error** as below:

[image]

> **Note** that: Tokens generated for Microsoft Graph API shouldn't be validated as it is not meant for the application. Only Microsoft Graph can validate tokens issued for MS Graph itself as suggested by *Sérgio Correia.*

Only the access token generated for your application can be validated.

Hence, to resolve the error you can **Expose an API** like below:

[image]

Added the API permissions:

[image]

I generated access token by passing **scope** as **`api://ClientID/test.read`**

[image]

***Now the Signature Verified successfully like below:***

[image]